# How to send List of objects and image from jQuery to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I have some model classes:

```
public class Research
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper ImageFile { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ResearchAuthors> ResearchAuthors { get; set; }
}

public class ResearchAuthors
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int ResearchId { get; set; }
    public Research Research { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

This is the jQuery code how I'm getting the data to be sent to the controller

```
        var Research = {
            Id: idInput.val(),
            Title: titleInput.val(),
            Abstract: abstractInput.val(),
            ImageFile: imageInput.get(0).files[0],
            Body: bodyInput.val()
        };

        // Research Authors
        var ResearchAuthors = [];
        $('#authors-tbody tr').each(function () {
            var AuthorId = $(this).children('.id-td').text();
            var Id = $(this).children('.researchAuthorsId-td').text();
            var ResearchAuthor = {
                AuthorId: AuthorId,
                Id: Id,
                ResearchId: idInput.val()
            }
            ResearchAuthors.push(ResearchAuthor)
        });
```

The controller is waiting for this

```
public ActionResult Create(SaveResearchViewModel viewModel)
{
      return Json(new { success = true, message = "Created Successfully" });
}
```

The `SaveResearchViewModel` code:

```
public class SaveResearchViewModel
{
    public Research Research { get; set; }
    public List<ResearchAuthors> ResearchAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

I have used formdata but it won't work because of List of `ResearchAuthors` even can't stringify because of there is image with data to be send

So what is the proper way to use with all different data types [Object, Object.Image, Arr[Object]] in order to receive in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to pass 1 string to Controller. Then serializer into an object.

```
var Research = {
Id: idInput.val(),
Title: titleInput.val(),
Abstract: abstractInput.val(),
ImageFile: imageInput.get(0).files[0],
Body: bodyInput.val()};

$.ajax({
url:'/Controller/Action',
data: {
    strResearch: JSON.stringify(Research)
},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
    if(res.success)
    {
        alert(res.message)
    }
}
```

//Controller

```
    public JsonResult Create(string strResearch)
    {
        SaveResearchViewModel saveResearchViewModel = new SaveResearchViewModel();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Research objResearch = serializer.Deserialize<Research>(strResearch);
        //save db

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Created Successfully" });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

form data can't add list of objects so instead you can use 2 ajax request first ajax save the Research and ReseachAuthors second ajax Save the image

like this

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/Researches/Create",
                data: viewModel,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Researches/SaveImage",
                            method: "POST",
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.success) {
                                    toastr.success(data.message);
                                    window.location.replace("/Researches/");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                toastr.error("Image Ajax error");
                            }
                        })   
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message)
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    toastr.error("Ajax Error")
                }
```